# How Do I expose an event to the caller implement, see code example?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, delegates

The idea here is to allow the caller to implement `AfterHTMLPieceHandler` for each cycle of the loop, I don't know if it is quite right or it should be an event insted or delegate. Honestly I don't know the difference, but this is another question.

```
//? Should it be static?
public static class PageScan
{
    public delegate string AfterHTMLPieceHandler();

    public static string GetHTML(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string html = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        sReader.Close();
        wResponse.Close();
        sReader.Dispose();
        return html;
    }

    public static void GetPiecesOfHtml(string html, string constantHtml)
    {
        while (html.IndexOf("http://portfoliopad.com/images/") > -1)
        {
            // it will retrieve a piece of html given the constantHtml and remove from html in order to break the loop in the end
            //How Do I hit the event for each time one cycle of the loop ends?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for ur downvote without comment, you make stackoverflow richer

Comment: You are creating a delegate but it's not pointing to any event from what I can see.. have you looked up how to do anonymous delegates or how to use / create delegates..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference on using delegates:[Understanding Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11657/Understanding-Delegates-in-C). Take note of the delegate Instance in the main part of the example, and how it is tied to the method the delegate is pointing to. I hope this helps.